# How does one add a tutorial feature to an app?

Tags: android

I'm curious as to how can I add a sort of tutorial feature in my app similar to the attached image where it seems like there is a layer on top of the app (the homescreen, in this case).[image: screenshot of android emulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView It does exactly what you show on the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

To create an layer on top of your view you can create your main view in the RelativeLayout or FrameLayout and add a new view can be a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout to the main view and set the background of the new view as alpha black (`<color name="alphablack">#80000000</color>`) and this is a code sample :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rlContainerMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="HELLO WORLD!"/>

          <RelativeLayout 
               android:id="@+id/rlLayer"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:background="@color/alphablack"
               android:visibility="gone">
          </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

at first set the visibility of the layer to gone and if you want the layer to be shown you can set the visibility with view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) and after the tutorial complete you can dismiss it with view.setVisibility(View.GONE). I hope my answer can help you but if you have another question about my answer feel free to ask in the comment :)